# should I wrap my try catch block inside of the for loop RTK QUERY?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I use rtk query and make optimistic UI. So I select by endpoints and change the data but there is one thing. I have a constant varibale "patchResult" in my for loop and outer for loop I await my query fullfilled. So I can not patchResult.undo() because patchResult variable is inside the for loop and my try catch block is outer the for loop so I dont have access to the variable. Should I put the try catch block in the for loop or is it bad ?

```
      async onQueryStarted({ user_id }, { dispatch, queryFulfilled, getState }) {
         for (const { endpointName, originalArgs } of Api.util.selectInvalidatedBy(getState(), [{ type: 'USER'}])) { 
          
          const patchResult = dispatch(
            UserApi.util.updateQueryData('users', originalArgs, (draft) => {
              return {
                ...draft,
                user: {
                  ...draft.user,
                  is_follow: !draft.user.is_follow
                }
              }
            })
          );
        }

       try {
          await queryFulfilled
        } catch {
          patchResult.undo();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need an array of patches:

```js
async function onQueryStarted(
  { user_id },
  { dispatch, queryFulfilled, getState }
) {
  let allPatches = [];

  for (const { endpointName, originalArgs } of Api.util.selectInvalidatedBy(
    getState(),
    [{ type: "USER" }]
  )) {
    const patchResult = dispatch(
      UserApi.util.updateQueryData("users", originalArgs, (draft) => {
        return {
          ...draft,
          user: {
            ...draft.user,
            is_follow: !draft.user.is_follow,
          },
        };
      })
    );

    allPatches.push(patchResult);
  }

  try {
    await queryFulfilled;
  } catch {
    for (const patchResult of allPatches) {
      patchResult.undo();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice man thank you very much! if I have mutliple patchResults then I should make it like this: allPatches.push(patchResult); allPatches.push(patchResult2); ... or is there a better solution ?

Comment: `allPatches.push(patchResult, patchResult2);` would probably work too - totally depends on what you see as more readable.